# Python - Plot 2 Plots together

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two graphs individually and I want to display them on the same plot.

This is my plot 1 code

```
ax1= concatenated_data_cleaned.groupby(['Cat1', 'Cat2']).median()[['Measure']].unstack()
ax1.plot.bar(rot =0)
plt.xlabel("Cat Names")
plt.ylabel("Measures")
plt.title("Title 1")
plt.show()
```

This is my plot 2 Code,

```
ax2= concatenated_data_cleaned.groupby(['Cat2', 'Cat1']).median()[['Measure']].unstack()
ax1.plot.bar(rot =0)
plt.xlabel("Cat Names")
plt.ylabel("Measures")
plt.title("Title 2")
plt.show()
```

Now, this gets shown in different graph (image) one after another. How Can I show this in the same graph - one below another in the same graph (image).

Kindly help me with this.

This is what I am trying,

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
df1= concatenated_data_cleaned.groupby(['Cat1', 'Cat2']).median()[['Measure']].unstack()
ax1 = df1.plot.bar(rot =0)
df2= concatenated_data_cleaned.groupby(['Cat2', 'Cat1']).median()[['Measure']].unstack()
ax2 = df2.plot.bar(rot =0)
ax1.plt.bar(rot=0, ax=axes[0])
ax2.plt.bar(rot=0, ax=axes[1])
plt.show()
```

And it is not working for me.

Comment: How exactly is it not working?

Comment: It says 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'plt'

Comment: Oh I see. I had a typo.  Let me edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable naming is a bit unconventional. `ax` typically is used for a matplotlib Axes object. Here you have a dataframe.

Regardless, you should set up a figure with two axes. `plt.subplots` is an easy way to do this. It will return the figure and an array with all the axes that you create. You can even set the axis to be equal between the two with `sharex` and `sharey`. Use the axes objects in your plotting call for each dataframe:

```
df1= concatenated_data_cleaned.groupby(['Cat1', 'Cat2']).median()[['Measure']].unstack()
df2= concatenated_data_cleaned.groupby(['Cat2', 'Cat1']).median()[['Measure']].unstack()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
df1.plot.bar(rot=0, ax=axes[0])
df2.plot.bar(rot=0, ax=axes[1])
axes[0].set_title('Title 0')
axes[1].set_title('Title 1')
plt.show()
```